# How do you change <title> of a Satchmo Store?

Tags: python, django, satchmo

This seems like something that should be obvious, but I simply can't find it.

I created a Satchmo store using clonesatchmo.py, as indicated by the [installation instructions](http://www.satchmoproject.com/docs/dev/new_installation.html).

I have tried to change the name of the site through the admin interface (going to Sites and changing the display name) and by editing local_setting.py, changing the line:

`SITE_NAME = "Simple Satchmo"`

to

`SITE_NAME = "Anything Else"`

By neither change impacts the actual store. Simple Satchmo remains in the title field, mocking me. So, what idiotic thing am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to Admin, Store configurations and change the Store Name for your store.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the tittle by web site Admin on both `Shop / Store Configuration: Store Name`.
and `Sites / Sites: Display Name`. They should be the same.
The latter name is used by some utils related to Django, like sending registration email.

Setting the line `SITE_NAME` has any effect only **before** the first running "clonesatchmo.py" or "manage.py satchmo_load_store". Note that the line is preceded by a comment
`# These are used when loading the test data`

This is not enough explanatory IMO. I will suggest in the development team to remove it by installation script in Satchmo 0.9.3. It will be at least better explained  now.